# Checking items in a ListView by Default

Tags: java, android, listview, simplecursoradapter

I have a `ListView` (actually a `ListFragment`, but I believe they are functionally essentially the same) that is backed by a `SimpleCursorAdapter`.  When the fragment is loaded, it is passed a `long[]` of `ids` that represent the items to be checked by default.  So when the data has finished loading from the database, I need to "check" the items in the view that have are contained in the list of ids.

How would I do this?  It seems like such a simple task, and I can figure out the logic necessary to perform the actual "checking".  But I can't figure out where to place the logic so that it will work properly.  I tried putting it in the `onViewCreated(View, Bundle)` method, but the `View` passed in is not a `ListView` and I don't know how to iterate though the views returned by `getListView()`.